# OSError Read-only django

Tags: python, django

При попытке создать запись модели в базе данных получаю ошибку `[Errno 30] Read-only file system`.Модель имеет ImageField без которой все работает. Проблема при сохранение изображения. В ручную во вью и через админку джанго пробовал не получается.

Comment: если вы попробуете файл создать в месте куда django пытается писать, то что происходит?

Answer (score 0):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'media_root')
```

помогла эта строчка кода в settings.py

Comment: Не нужно вкладывать media в static. Вы не решили проблему, вы спрятались от неё костылём

Comment: @andreymal  а что нужно было сделать?

Comment: Например, ответить на вопрос, который вам задал jfs, а дальше разобрались бы

Comment: @andreyma при создании файла такая же ошибка oserror

Comment: При создании файла где? Какой путь, какой диск, какая файловая система? Какая операционная система, в конце концов? Ошибка «Read-only file system» в некоторых запущенных случаях может намекать на то, что диск вот-вот рассыпется нахрен, так что лучше не оставляйте это на авось

Comment: @andreyma На хостинге. Операционная система убунту. Создать пытался файл в скрипте views.py в папку app/static/image/

Comment: Во-первых, папка static, как следует из её названия, предназначена для статических файлов, а не для постоянно создающихся/меняющихся, и не надо в ней ничего создавать из views.py. Во-вторых, путь явно неполный, а про диск и файловую систему вы не ответили. Файловые системы обычно не уходят в read-only режим просто так, у вас или у хостинга что-то сломалось. Ну или хостинг у вас очень странный. // Впрочем, в любом случае проблема не имеет никакого отношения ни к Django, ни к Python

Comment: @andreyma еще один вопрос. По какому url могу получить изображения из медиа

Comment: По тому, который указан в опции MEDIA_URL. А вот как сделать, чтобы адрес, указанный в MEDIA_URL, заработал - это уже зависит не от джанги, а от apache/nginx (если они есть) или от хостинга. Между прочим, каталога static это всё тоже касается

Comment: @andreyma Cпасибо. походу нужно искать другой хостинг)